# 3-SAT with negative-literals in each clause

Tags: 3-sat

Does a 3-SAT problem, where in each clause there is at least a negative-literal, always has a solution?

After looking at it, seems to me that the answer is yes, but maybe there is something I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the all-zeroes assignment, $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=0$.

What if all clauses have a positive literal?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enough information to determine if there is a solution, if all literals where positive I would say that there isn't any solution.